# How do I remove an IPAddress that doesn't have an adapter

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, adapter

I have 4 results (2 IPv4, 2 IPv6) when I query Get-NetIpAddress that do not have a corresponding network adapter. What are these addresses and how can I remove them?

I have tried to Remove-NetIpAddress but after a few seconds they pop back up.

Example:

```
C:\Users\will> Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex 15


IPAddress         : fe80::50c7:f528:d39a:938b%15
InterfaceIndex    : 15
InterfaceAlias    : Local Area Connection* 11
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 64
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Deprecated
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : 169.254.147.139
InterfaceIndex    : 15
InterfaceAlias    : Local Area Connection* 11
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 16
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Tentative
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

C:\Users\will> Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex 15
Get-NetAdapter : No MSFT_NetAdapter objects found with property 'InterfaceIndex' equal to '15'.  Verify the value of
the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex 15
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (15:UInt32) [Get-NetAdapter], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_InterfaceIndex,Get-NetAdapter
```

Full IP result for IPv4:

```
C:\Users\will> (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex 15)[1] | select -Property *


PrefixOrigin             : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin             : Link
Type                     : Unicast
Store                    : ActiveStore
AddressFamily            : IPv4
AddressState             : Tentative
ifIndex                  : 15
Caption                  :
Description              :
ElementName              :
InstanceID               :
CommunicationStatus      :
DetailedStatus           :
HealthState              :
InstallDate              :
Name                     : ;@C8<?>8;>A8;=C55;?55;55;
OperatingStatus          :
OperationalStatus        :
PrimaryStatus            :
Status                   :
StatusDescriptions       :
AvailableRequestedStates :
EnabledDefault           : 2
EnabledState             :
OtherEnabledState        :
RequestedState           : 12
TimeOfLastStateChange    :
TransitioningToState     : 12
CreationClassName        :
SystemCreationClassName  :
SystemName               :
NameFormat               :
OtherTypeDescription     :
ProtocolIFType           : 4096
ProtocolType             :
Address                  :
AddressOrigin            : 0
AddressType              :
IPv4Address              : 169.254.147.139
IPv6Address              :
IPVersionSupport         :
PrefixLength             : 16
SubnetMask               :
InterfaceAlias           : Local Area Connection* 11
InterfaceIndex           : 15
IPAddress                : 169.254.147.139
PreferredLifetime        : 10675199.02:48:05.4775807
SkipAsSource             : False
ValidLifetime            : 10675199.02:48:05.4775807
PSComputerName           :
CimClass                 : ROOT/StandardCimv2:MSFT_NetIPAddress
CimInstanceProperties    : {Caption, Description, ElementName, InstanceID...}
CimSystemProperties      : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

Answer (score 2):

The 169.254.147.139 is an APIPA address which means that the client is soliciting network configuration dynamically, this is, a DHCP server but it doesn't get an answer from any server so it gets that type of IP address that somehow is useless in communications. Thus, my best affirmation is that even if you remove the IP address with the PowerShell command the adapter will try to get a new configuration with DHCP (again) but since no server/router might be available at the time it'll get reassigned an APIPA address once again. Hope that helps!

P.S. My answer is based on the posted information.